# What fonts are these t-shirts (I'm a wild one / Ain't nobody got time for that)?

Tags: font-identification

Trying to figure out what font these are?  I have tried dafont and WhatTheFont.

[image: I’m a Wild One Black Tee]

[image: Ain't Nobody Got Time for That Tee]

Comment: It's too late now since both fonts have been identified, but in the future it would be better to post this as two separate questions

Comment: did you find out what the font is on the I'm a wild one shirt?

Answer (score 10):

I'm pretty sure the second one is [Simon Script](http://www.dafont.com/simon-script.font):

[image]

Comment: Yes. Have a +1.

Answer (score 8):

The top one is a decorated version of [Eccentric](http://www.identifont.com/link?BEGT4Q+2YGA), almost certainly a bespoke hand-drawn customisation:

[image: Eccentric via Identifont]

While the second example is a font (repeated letters are identical), it seems likely to be hand-drawn and the repeated letters simply cut and pasted.